# weblogic domain server.out log file manually modified locked

Tags: file, logging, weblogic

I have a 2 questions regarding Weblogic.
I am using Weblogic 10.3.6.
Yesterday I deployed the war file. 
Following are my 2 questions

1) When I restart the server the sys out logs at location 
domains//servers//logs/Server-name.out 
domains//servers//logs/Server-name.log
are not getting updated

Actually logs were getting updated initially but I cleared the log file by manually opening the log file and deleting its content.

Later I found on official oracle website that
"Oracle recommends that you do not modify log files by editing them manually. Modifying a file changes the timestamp and can confuse log file rotation. In addition, editing a file might lock it and prevent updates from WebLogic Server, as well as interfere with the Accessor"

I think my log files got locked due to above reason.
Is there any way I can do to get updates in log files.

I have restarted the server as well but the logs are not getting updated.

2) I have deployed my web application using packed war file. When I deploy using war file it is expected that the war file gets exploded at some temporarily location in weblogic server. War gets deployed successfully but when I checked the contents of 
WEBLOGIC/bea10.3.6.0_BI/user_projects/domains/Managedserver_7011_7012/servers/Server-chanakya/tmp/_WL_user
It is blank.
I was expecting that war should get exploaded inside the _WL_user folder. But it is not happeining right now.

Please let me know what I can do with respect to above problems.
Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First question:

Generally speaking the `.out` file is created during server start and not updated once the server reaches the `RUNNING` state. The .log file should be updated continually however. It is safe to delete both of these files and once the server is restarted they should be regenerated. If for some reason they are not, go to `server name -> Logging tab -> Log file name` and specify the full path and name for a new log file.

Second question:

If you chose `nostage` for your deployment, it will not be copied to your server and will live wherever the file originally was. `stage` mode should copy the file to `tmp/_WL_user` after starting out under a `stage` directory. You can remove your deployment from the weblogic admin  console and also delete the tmp and cache folders and try the deployment again if you need to. It's also possible the deployment failed... check the Deployments link in the admin console to make sure it reached the `Active` state.

Last - welcome to Stack Overflow. In general you should ask one question at a time.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your reply. In my case it was a clustered deployment. Admin server was running but node manager for one of the server was not running. Once I restarted the node manager logs got updated and after that I deployed my war and it got copied in WEBLOGIC/bea10.3.6.0_BI/user_projects/domains/Managedserver_7011_7012/servers/Server-chanakya/tmp/_WL_user
Thankx a lot